# What's the meaning of "error_subcode"

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

What's the meaning of "error_subcode" in error information?

Can we make sure the error type by Analyzing "error" and "error_subcode"?

Do facebook has official explanation about  the "error_subcode"?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you expand on your question?

Answer (score 1):

As described in an old stub from Facebook

> Along with a human-readable message, error responses include an `error_subcode` that describes the nature of the error. Although you can generally only respond to these errors by reauthenticating the user, you can use these subcodes for internal logging purposes or to better explain why you're asking the user to log in again. The possible codes and their meaning are below:

```
`error_subcode` Meaning
456  The session is malformed.
457  The session has an invalid origin.
458  The session is invalid, because the app is no longer installed.
459  The user has been checkpointed. The error_data will contain the URL the user needs to go to to clear the checkpoint.
460  The session is invalid likely because the user changed the password.
461  The session is invalid, because the user has reinstalled the app.
462  The session has a stale version.
463  The session has expired.
464  The session user is not confirmed.
465  The session user is invalid.
466  The session was explicitly invalidated through an API call.
467  The session is invalid, because the user logged out.
468  The session is invalid, because the user has not used the app for a long time.
```